# Android Parceable issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently trying to pass a `parceablearraylist` from `mylogin` activity to my main activity but getting a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.muuves.introround/com.muuves.introround.activities.MainActivity}:    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41ef90a8: Unmarshalling unknown type  code 7536741 at offset 684
```

Here are my `parceable` objects

```
    public class Challenge implements Parcelable {

private Integer id;
private Integer challenger_id;
private Integer friend_id;
private String artist_name;
private String song_name;
private String image_url;
private String song_url;
private String answer_url;
private int challenge_attempts_left;
private int answer;
private Person person;
private Person friend;

public Challenge() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Integer getChallenger_id() {
    return challenger_id;
}
public void setChallenger_id(Integer challenger_id) {
    this.challenger_id = challenger_id;
}

public Integer getFriend_id() {
    return friend_id;
}
public void setFriend_id(Integer friend_id) {
    this.friend_id = friend_id;
}
public String getArtist_name() {
    return artist_name;
}
public void setArtist_name(String artist_name) {
    this.artist_name = artist_name;
}
public String getSong_name() {
    return song_name;
}
public void setSong_name(String song_name) {
    this.song_name = song_name;
}
public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}
public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}
public String getSong_url() {
    return song_url;
}
public void setSong_url(String song_url) {
    this.song_url = song_url;
}
public String getAnswer_url() {
    return answer_url;
}
public void setAnswer_url(String answer_url) {
    this.answer_url = answer_url;
}
public int getChallenge_attempts_left() {
    return challenge_attempts_left;
}
public void setChallenge_attempts_left(int challenge_attempts_left) {
    this.challenge_attempts_left = challenge_attempts_left;
}
public int getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
public void setAnswer(int answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}
public Person getFriend() {
    return friend;
}

public void setFriend(Person friend) {
    this.friend = friend;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(challenger_id);
    dest.writeInt(friend_id);
    dest.writeString(artist_name);
    dest.writeString(image_url);
    dest.writeString(song_url);
    dest.writeString(answer_url);
    dest.writeInt(challenge_attempts_left);
    dest.writeInt(answer);
    dest.writeParcelable(person, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(friend, flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Challenge> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Challenge>() {
    @Override
    public Challenge createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Challenge challenge = new Challenge();
        challenge.setId(in.readInt());
        challenge.setChallenger_id(in.readInt());
        challenge.setFriend_id(in.readInt());
        challenge.setArtist_name(in.readString());
        challenge.setSong_name(in.readString());
        challenge.setImage_url(in.readString());
        challenge.setSong_url(in.readString());
        challenge.setAnswer_url(in.readString());
        challenge.setChallenge_attempts_left(in.readInt());
        challenge.setAnswer(in.readInt());
        challenge.setPerson((Person) in.readParcelable(Person.class.getClassLoader()));
        challenge.setFriend((Person) in.readParcelable(Person.class.getClassLoader()));
        return challenge;
    }

    @Override
    public Challenge[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Challenge[size];
    }
};


}

public class Person implements Parcelable {

private int id;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private String image_url;

public Person(){
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst_Name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_Name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_Name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_Name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}

public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(first_name);
    dest.writeString(last_name);
    dest.writeString(image_url);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(in.readInt());
        person.setFirst_Name(in.readString());
        person.setLast_Name(in.readString());
        person.setImage_url(in.readString());
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] newArray(int size) {
        return null;
    }
};
}
```

Login activity

```
        @Override
    public void preLoadDetails(Details details) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("receive", details.getReceive());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

MainActivity

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Challenge> friends = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("receive");

    mContent = new MainFragment(0);
    mContent.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    // set the Above View
    setContentView(R.layout.home_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent).commit();

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment()).commit();

    // Disable
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
}
```

Been trying to fix it for the pass day and getting no where all I know is that person `parceable` object in the challenge object are always null but they are not when I put them in the bundle.

Appreciate any input.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with having two of the same parceable objects types ie person, they seem to interfere with each other in challenge when i remove one it fixes but i really need both of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it was actually very simple, forgot song url when i was writing to the parcel. Any when i missed that write that was why i was getting the weird exception for person object. it was expecting a person object but was getting something else. 1 day wasted oh well :(

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(challenger_id);
    dest.writeInt(friend_id);
    dest.writeString(artist_name);
    **dest.writeString(song_name);**
    dest.writeString(image_url);
    dest.writeString(song_url);
    dest.writeString(answer_url);
    dest.writeInt(challenge_attempts_left);
    dest.writeInt(answer);
    dest.writeParcelable(person, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(friend, flags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those `Integer` type could be `null` or an `int`, you need to handle that situation properly.

For example I have utility functions like this :

```
static public Integer readInteger(Parcel in){
    if(in.readInt() == 1){
        return in.readInt();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

static public void writeInteger(Integer value, Parcel out){
    if(value != null){
        out.writeInt(1);
        out.writeInt(value);
    }else{
        out.writeInt(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing in the class Challenge you use Integer attributes and you parce "int" those are 2 diferents things.

Exemple of how i do things myself :

```
public Podcast(Parcel parcel) {
    id = parcel.readLong();
    title = parcel.readString();
    subtitle = parcel.readString();
    summary = parcel.readString();
    duration = parcel.readString();
    author = parcel.readString();
    date = parcel.readString();
    mp3 = parcel.readString();
    podcastCategoryId = parcel.readLong();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // not used
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(id);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(subtitle);
    dest.writeString(summary);
    dest.writeString(duration);
    dest.writeString(author);
    dest.writeString(date);
    dest.writeString(mp3);
    dest.writeLong(podcastCategoryId);
}

public static Creator<Podcast>  CREATOR = new Creator<Podcast>() {

                                            public Podcast createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
                                                return new Podcast(parcel);
                                            }

                                            public Podcast[] newArray(int size) {
                                                return new Podcast[size];
                                            }
                                        };
```

Comment: This was working fine when i was passing between fragments but seems to stop when i needed a separate activity for logging in because of design decisions.

Comment: Between activities you use   intent.putExtra("...", object);  AND getIntent().getParcelableExtra("...");  ?

Comment: you also can do it as so Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putParcelableArrayList("receive", details.getReceive()); intent.putExtras(bundle);

Comment: Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras(); ArrayList<Challenge> friends = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("receive");

Comment: You should use bundle for fragment communication, and intent for activities (just an advice)

Comment: you are wrong, you can use both. Why would android sdk give you the option to put a bundle in the extras so?

Comment: Well you are right, both can be use, but using extra can prevent some bugs since you don't use the bundle direclty. Just sayin, when you have some blocking issue you should try things out event when it doesn't seems to be "that" solution, it could be part of it :/

Comment: I have tried that idea yesterday a couple of times already same issue

Comment: When you use the putextra in the background android wrapping the extra in a bundle in the intent.

Comment: Yep so you don't manipulate the bundle directly, sometimes it can helps. Anyway, the only thing i see in your code is that you writeInt and readInt with  Integers which can be a problem since a premitive type and a class are not the same

Comment: There seems to be a problem with having two of the same parceable objects types ie person, they seem to interfere with each other in challenge when i remove one it fixes but i really need both of the objects.

Comment: maybe you can try to make two class "Friend and some other" that extend the mother class Person

Comment: annd you should also complete the newsArray method of Person

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Person[] newArray(int size) {
    return null;
}
```

You should create there an array of that size and return it.

```
@Override
public Person[] newArray(int size) {
    return new Person[size];
}
```

Comment: No that makes no difference, its a single person object not an array. I tried it anyway and still never worked.